# MVC 4: How to make DropDownListFor return 0 as optionLabel value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a create view with multiple DropDownListFors. Each time a new object is created only 1 of the DropDownListFors should have a value, I want the others to return 0 as the result when the optionLabel is left selected.

How do I assign 0 as the value for a DropDownListFor's optionLabel?

EDIT:
Here is an example of my DropDownListFor code in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cardReward.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.cardReward, "Id","Name"), "None")
```

When I render the page it creates the list with None at the top like this:

```
<option value>None</option>
```

I want it to be like this:

```
<option value="0">None</option>
```

Comment: Do you have some code that you have tried? This will help us get a better understand of what you want to achieve.

Comment: In your controller action, replace null with zero.

Comment: Added some example code and an example of what I'm getting/what I want to get.

Comment: In replacement/addition to ataravati's comment, some    [(nullablething) ?? 0] could help!

Comment: Can you post your Model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the [documentation for DropDownFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) the `optionLabel` parameter (where you're passing "None") is described as:

> The text for a default empty item.

So this is designed to always be an empty item.  You will need to add an additional item into your select list in order to get a 0 value.

I have used the following extension method to accomplish this (sorry untested, there may be minor errors):

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> InsertEmptyFirst(this IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list, string emptyText = "", string emptyValue = "")
{
    return new [] { new SelectListItem { Text = emptyText, Value = emptyValue } }.Concat(list);
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cardReward.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.cardReward, "Id","Name").InsertEmptyFirst("None", "0"))
```

Comment: Thank you, is this then the best option for when you want to provide a user with the ability to not select an option from a drop down list?

Comment: This may look good, but it's so unnecessary in my opinion. The optionLabel in DropDownList gives you a null value that you can easily convert to 0 in your controller.

Comment: Actually, I get a new error now when I try to submit the form. I am told that the first dropdownlistfor encountered "Value cannot be null" by my debugger. I'm given this even if I select a value for the drop down. Any ideas?

Comment: @ataravati My view does not allow me to submit a null value for the dropdowns, how do I disable validation for a dropdownlistfor?

Comment: This got me started, but what worked best was http://stackoverflow.com/a/30582746/1385857

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new empty string, here's an example.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectID, Model.Projects, string.Empty)
```

Comment: No, the value will be null, not `0`.