# Adding a "Please Select" option to a html.dropdownlist with an array SelectList []

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question in my MVC application which requires a dropdown list and I want to add a "Please select" option to the dropdown to hide the answers until it is clicked.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QuestionTwo, new SelectList
(new[]{"A","B", "C", "D"}))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionTwo)
```

Because of the way I have created my list of answers, I'm not sure how to add a default "Please Select" value that cannot be selected by the user.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QuestionTwo, new SelectList
(new[]{"A","B", "C", "D"}),"Please Select")`. Here you go.

Comment: You can do it by JavaScript or adding an empty value in your list at the beginning or extend DropDownListFor method ... What are the constraints ?

Comment: Or you can also see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153328/mvc-4-how-to-make-dropdownlistfor-return-0-as-optionlabel-value

Comment: Adding Please Select to the end of the selectList will not work because it means that can be accepted as an answer, I want it to say Please Select but not allow that to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

a good way to do this is like

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select something...</option>
```

I found it on this thread 
[How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Best bet would be to use jQuery to add this option ad the top

```
$('select').append('<option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>');
```