# how to add a selectlistitem to a selectlist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following select list

```
 public SelectList StaffList { get; set; }
```

I am assigning it the following,

```
inspectorCorrespondences.StaffList = new SelectList(userDetails, "Id", "FullName");
```

but I want to add in another SelectList item

```
 var systemGeneratedUser = new SelectListItem() { Value = "-1", Text = "System Generated" };
```

how do I do that?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668589/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-selectlist-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx), it looks like you need to initialize the `SelectList` with the values instead of adding them.  Passing an enumerable of `SelectListItem` to the constructor appears to be the expected way.

It *looks like* you're already doing that in the sense that `userDetails` is already an enumeration?  If so, what type of enumeration is it?  You may need to add a line or two of code to transform it to an enumeration of `SelectListItem` objects, add yours to that, and then use that to initialize the `SelectList`.  Maybe something like this:

```
var listItems = userDetails.Select(u => new SelectListItem { Value = u.Id, Text = u.FullName }).ToList();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "-1", Text = "System Generated" });
// or perhaps .Insert() at position 0 instead?
inspectorCorrespondences.StaffList = new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: David - thanks.. I had to make one change in the last line  inspectorCorrespondences.StaffList = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");

Comment: @user2206329: Interesting.  I would have thought the object would be smart enough to interpret the value/text fields if the enumeration is of `SelectListItem`, but I guess your testing has indicated otherwise.  Either way, I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't necessarily the most elegant solution, but you'll need to cast the SelectList's items to a list of SelectListItems if you want to add another SelectListItem.

```
        var myItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        myItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "AA", Value = "11" } );

        var mySelectList = new SelectList(myItems);

        ((List<SelectListItem>)mySelectList.Items).Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "BB", Value = "22" });
```