# add extra option to an already populated dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an html dropdownlistfor which is being populated from my database, this I was able to do successfully but the issue I am having now is including an additional option not available in the database as an option that can also be selected.it is actually a list of items but I want a give an option ALL which when selected means the user is selecting all the items displayed in the database, my major issue is how to include the ALL option. I have searched and read similar questions but they are not what am trying to achieve. thanks for your help. here is my code
in my controller I have this:

```
var load = from bh in db.IV_001_ITEM
                           select bh;
               ViewBag.selection = new SelectList(load.ToList(), "item_code", "item_name", glay.vwstring2);
```

in my view I have this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
                 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.vwstring2, ViewBag.selection as SelectList, "Select", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", id = "selectc" } )
        </div>
```

Comment: There's a few good ways to do this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668589/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-selectlist-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: thanks, I will check that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method to explicitly add an extra option (`SelectListItem`)

```
List<SelectListItem> optionList = db.IV_001_ITEM
                                    .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value=x.item.code,
                                                         Text=x.itemName}).ToList();
// Now add the item you want

optionList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="Foo",Text="Bar"});

//use this now
ViewBag.Items = optionList;

// You can set the selected item on your view model property
myViewModelObject.vwstring2 = glay.vwstring2; //For the selected item
return View(myViewModelObject);
```

In your view,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.vwstring2, ViewBag.Items as List<SelectListItem>,
                                                "Select", new { @class = "form-control"})
```