# How to add a none field in a dropdown for accepting a none value in database in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

In controller

```
ViewBag.free_item = 
    new SelectList(db.prd01category
                     .Where(x => x.prd01StoreID == _ActiveSession.StoreID && 
                                 x.prd01deleted == false && 
                                 x.prd01active == true)
                     .ToList(), "prd01uin", "prd01name");
```

In view

```
<div class="control-label col-md-2">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dis04coupon_code_offer.dis04prd01uin_free_item, "Free Item")
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.DropDownList("free_item", null, "Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control search-select FreeItem Item", id = "Items", @data_target = "subItems", @Name = "dis04coupon_code_offer.dis04prd01uin_free_item" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dis04coupon_code_offer.dis04prd01uin_free_item, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: For a "None" value, can you just add it to your `SelectList` before setting it in the `Viewbag`?

Comment: There are a few options listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668589/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-selectlist-in-asp-net-mvc